# How to secure S3 download for user sensitve data?

Tags: security, amazon-s3

Suppose we have a web application for ebook shopping, users can only download books they have paid. And all those ebooks data(like epub data) are stored in S3, users will got a S3 download url when our app validated the user already bought one book.

I know S3 will generate a temporary and time-limited URLs to the user.  But the problem is even the url is temporary and time-limited, what will happen if by any chance another user get the temporary url within the limited time?

Ok so one way seems to be letting the limited-time very short, like 10 seconds, but the potential risks still there.

I know this question is rigorous, how would you deal with it? Or forget it?

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is that the buyer would distribute the URL, they could equally well distribute the file they've downloaded.

If the concern is that someone would get hold of the URL without the buyer's knowledge, then perhaps you could protect the download with a token that only the buyer would know (e.g. a password of some sort). This would make the URL unusable to anyone other than the buyer. The downside is that this will inconvenience the very people who've paid for your product.